# How do I set value of an entry in a nested dictionary in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

In this [dict for](http://wiki.tcl.tk/19941) example:

How do I change the values of fields forenames, surname, street, city and phone? I tried this way:

```
dict for {id info} $employeeInfo {
    puts "Employee #[incr i]: $id"
    dict with info {
        puts "   Name: $forenames $surname"
        puts "   Address: $street, $city"
        puts "   Telephone: $phone"

        set [dict get $employeeInfo $id phone] 2341

        puts "   New Telephone: $phone"

    }
}
```

The phone is set with a new value via:

```
set [dict get $employeeInfo $id phone] 12345
```

It doesn't work. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `phone` element is under the `info` element, so:

```
dict set employeeInfo $info phone 12345
```

provides that you know the `info` element.

#### UPDATE

In the `with` context, you can set the phone element directly, try it:

```
dict with info {
    ...
    dict set phone 12345
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dict set` command can set elements of nested dictionaries:

```
dict set employeeInfo $id phone 12345
```

Note that the enclosing `dict for` loop will not see the change; it (conceptually) takes a copy of the dictionary before iterating over it.